# Strange behavior with jquery event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's one for the jquery masters:

This works:

```
$(function (){
    $("#<?= $gridArr['event_id'] ?> .gallery-add").each(function() {
        var $dialog = $("<div></div>");
        var $link = $(this).one("click", function() {
            $dialog
                .load($link.attr("href"))
                .dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 520,
                    height: 180,
                    title: $link.attr("title")
                });
            $link.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog("open");                                    
                return false;
            });        
            alert('clicked');           
            $(document).bind('uploadDone', function(e) {
               // alert("dialogCloser triggered in dialog function");
                $dialog.dialog("close"); 
                $("#<?= $gridArr['uniq'] ?>-event-path-form-submit").trigger('click');   
            });                         
            return false; 
        });

    });
});
```

This doesn't:

```
$(function (){
    $("#<?= $gridArr['event_id'] ?> .gallery-add").each(function() {
        var $dialog = $("<div></div>");
        var $link = $(this).one("click", function() {
            $dialog
                .load($link.attr("href"))
                .dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 520,
                    height: 180,
                    title: $link.attr("title")
                });
            $link.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog("open");                                    
                return false;
            });        
            // alert('clicked');           
            $(document).bind('uploadDone', function(e) {
               // alert("dialogCloser triggered in dialog function");
                $dialog.dialog("close"); 
                $("#<?= $gridArr['uniq'] ?>-event-path-form-submit").trigger('click');   
            });                         
            return false; 
        });

    });
});
```

The only difference is the alert statement.  Basically what I'm doing here is attaching a bunch of click event handlers to images, which bring up ajax upload forms in dialogs. The upload form dumps the images to an iframe. The iframe then triggers an the uploadDone handler which is bound to $(document), and that triggers another click event.

The only difference is the presence of the alert statement.  I take that line out, and the dialog fails to close.

Please tell me I just missed a semicolon or something stupid.... otherwise I was thinking of using delay().

Thanks.

---

Solution:

I finally arrived at this after an evening of goofing. I wasn't able to positively determine what was going on with the alert statement, or how to manage the asynchronous execution, but this worked around it.

```
var $dialog = $("<div></div>");
$(function (){    
    $("#event_22 .gallery-add").each(function() {
        var $link = $(this).one("click", function() {
            $dialog
                .load($link.attr("href"))
                .dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 520,
                    height: 180,
                    title: $link.attr("title")
                }).bind('uploadDone', function() {
                 // alert("uploadDone triggered in dialog function");
                 $("#myForm-submit").trigger('click');
            });
            $link.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog("open");                                    
                return false;
            });
            return false; 
        });       
    });
});
```

In the success iframe,

```
parent.$dialog.dialog("close");
parent.$dialog.trigger( 'uploadDone' );
```

Thanks a lot everyone for your help. Here are the changes I made to get this working:

- declared $dialog outside the function in the global scope
- bound the uploadDone event listener to $dialog prior to creating $link.click()
- changed id="22" to id="event_22" cause in html < 5, IDs have to start with alpha chars.

I'm not sure who's answer to accept, but I certainly appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Could you show the *rendered* as-seen-in-the-browser jQuery; because I'm pretty sure that the `<?= ... ?>` is a server-side script? JavaScript, and therefore jQuery, works client-side, so server-side is irrelevant. Also, what's the relevant HTML?

Comment: I'd love to but this block is loaded by ajax, so firefox view source doesn't show it, and for some reason it's not visible in firebug either.  Yes those are php short tags with some unique variables which you are right to want to examine. There could be a problem with those.

Comment: To partially answer your question, <?= $gridArr['event_id'] ?> is a numeric value. The div has id="22" so #<?= $gridArr['event_id'] ?> would be substituted with #22

Answer (score 5):

The alert statement is most likely causing a block which gives the code above it time to complete before the code below gets executed. My guess is that without the alert it's going all the way to the return false before it gets done with the upload.

Comment: Yes I would say this is what's happening, but I thought these things were supposed to happen sequentially?  I didn't realize that there was any parallel execution occuring with these type of statements.

Comment: Yes, load takes place asynchronously, therefore it and the code below it could be executing in parallel. Have you tried using console.log() instead of alert in order to see what order things are getting called in? Keep in mind if you do, that when asynchronous calls are made, the order in which things will complete is indeterminate.

Comment: It's difficult to know for sure how your code will run without knowing the exact logic of what you're trying to do, but it looks like you might be able to move some of the code around so that all the event binding is set up before the actual function calls begin. 

For example, try moving the  $(document).bind('uploadDone', function(e) { ... } to right before the var $link = $(this).one("click", function() { ... } code.

Comment: yep, I edited the original question with the solution I finally arrived at. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the dialog is loading before the uploadDone event is bound. Is there a reason you're binding it inside the click event handler, rather than when you create it?

```
$(function (){
  $("#<?= $gridArr['event_id'] ?> .gallery-add").each(function() {
    var $dialog = $("<div></div>");
    var $link = $(this).one("click", function() {
        $dialog
            .load($link.attr("href"))
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 520,
                height: 180,
                title: $link.attr("title")
            });
        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog("open");                                    
            return false;
        });           
        return false; 
    });
    $(document).bind('uploadDone', function(e) {
        // alert("dialogCloser triggered in dialog function");
        $dialog.dialog("close"); 
        $("#<?= $gridArr['uniq'] ?>-event-path-form-submit").trigger('click');   
    }); 

  });
});
```

It seems like this should work provided you always want all dialogs to close whenever uploadDone is broadcast. But, like David says in your question's comment... some context would be helpful

Comment: I tried this outside the link function and it doesn't trigger uploadDone.  I assume that is because $dialog.dialog happened inside of $link.

Comment: Say I want to bind uploadDone outside of $link, how can I reference the dialog properly outside that function?  It makes sense to bind it outside but I don't know how to refer to it inside that scope. I tried $link.$dialog but no dice. Thanks.

Comment: Let's make sure we're talking about the same thing here. Whether the uploadDone callback gets triggered has nothing to do with referencing the $dialog variable, or the .dialog() method on it.  If you uncomment that alert("dialogCloser..."); line in my example, does that get triggered?   Can you add a code snippet and an explanation from whatever triggers the uploadDone event?

Comment: Tested again and it doesn't get triggered in your example. When the upload success frame gets loaded, it runs: 
parent.$(parent.document).trigger("uploadDone"); which I know works, because it triggers the uploadDone when the alert statement is there.